# Cannot redeclare get_available_post_mime_types() error msg Wordpress Admin-Dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guys i believe my old wordpress site got hacked (db_version 38590) with the following error when trying to login over /wp-admin:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare get_available_post_mime_types() (previously declared in /www/htdocs/server/sitename.de/wp-includes/post.php:7139) in /www/htdocs/server/sitename.de/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 1092

The Frontend seemse to work without problem, tho i cant access the backend because of it atm.

I tried to find a new post.php to replace it with but found nothing on the internet since it's quite an old Wordpress version. Is there another way to fix my issue so i can access the backend again? sadly no backups are available

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue today,
I fixed it by replacing the wp-includes/post.php from backup
OR
You can obtain it from wordpress package as well